# Why is everyone so secretive about pricing for painting miniatures?

Tags: painting, miniatures

I have some Gloomhaven miniatures which I am trying to get painted.  I am trying to find the appropriate price to offer someone to paint these miniatures.

I went to https://www.reddit.com/r/brushforhire/ to try to figure out what this should cost.  Nobody posts prices!  I keep seeing messages like: "I sent you a PM with my prices."

This is super weird!  What's going on here?

Comment: While it's more work, asking multiple artists what they charge in order to determine fair market value is going to give you the answer you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my own personal experience, I have found that sellers do not publicly post their prices in order to remain competitive in the market. If they were to post their prices, a competitor can easily undermine that seller by decreasing their own prices for the same service in order to steal the customer and make the sale.  Furthermore, by not publicly posting prices, it allows a seller to assess each potential commission on a case-by-case basis, as often two projects are never completely identical in terms of time and effort.  Hope this helps!